# mysql query update duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, set, sql-update

I have a column called version in that there are numbers from 2-300.000.

In that column I have deleted some Version numbers, so the numbers are not continuous from 2-300.000, there are missing some numbers.

I need to correct it so it will be continuous again.
This is easy and could be done with

```
SET @ver := 1;
UPDATE geo_patch SET Version = ( SELECT @ver := @ver + 1 ) ORDER BY Version DESC;
```

My problem is there are duplicates with the same Version number, and I need to keep them as duplicates but still update them with a new version number.

Comment: You need a rank. Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function (the answer with 15 votes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update existing version numbers with a new, sequential number, but keep the duplicates in tact.  For this, use a `join` and calculate the new version in a subquery:

```
UPDATE geo_patch gp JOIN
       (select distinct version, (@ver := @ver + 1) as newver
        from geo_patch cross join (select @ver := 0) vars
        order by version
       ) gp2
       ON gp.version = gp2.version
    set gp.Version = gp2.newver;
```

MySQL can be finicky about variables with `group by`.  I'm not sure if the same weirdness exists with `distinct`.  So the above could put things in the wrong order.  The following should definitely work:

```
UPDATE geo_patch gp JOIN
       (select version, (@ver := @ver + 1) as newver
        from (select distinct version from geo_patch) gp2 cross join
             (select @ver := 0) vars
        order by version
       ) gp2
       ON gp.version = gp2.version
    set gp.Version = gp2.newver;
```